# Instantiating a constructor with parameters in an internal class with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have something along the lines of this:

```
object[] parameter = new object[1];
parameter[0] = x;
object instantiatedType =
Activator.CreateInstance(typeToInstantiate, parameter);
```

and

```
internal class xxx : ICompare<Type>
{
    private object[] x;

    # region Constructors

    internal xxx(object[] x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    internal xxx()
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

And I get:

threw exception:  System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'xxxx.xxx' not found..

Any ideas?

Comment: I originally though you intended `parameter` to be the thing you passed as `x`. However, I just realised that's probably not what you meant and, looking at the other answers, it seems I'm not alone. If this is correct, I suggest renaming `parameter` to `parameters`. Or better still, dispense with `parameter` altogether: `Activator.CreateInstance(typeToInstantiate, new object[]{x})`.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The issue is that [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type, object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) does not consider non-public constructors.

> **Exceptions**
>
> MissingMethodException: No matching
>   public constructor was found.

This is easily shown by changing the constructor to `public`visibility; the code then works correctly.

Here's one workaround (tested):

```
 BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
 CultureInfo culture = null; // use InvariantCulture or other if you prefer
 object instantiatedType =   
   Activator.CreateInstance(typeToInstantiate, flags, null, parameter, culture);
```

If you only require the parameterless constructor this will work as well:

```
//using the overload: public static object CreateInstance(Type type, bool nonPublic)
object instantiatedType = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToInstantiate, true)
```

Comment: I tested this and think it's worth mentioning that this method ONLY works with non-public constructors. To make it work with both public AND non-public constructors, change the `BindingFlags` to `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance`

Comment: Also you don't have to use object, you can use it like this: `YourType instantiatedType = (YourType)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YourType), true)`

Answer (score 33):

(tested successfully)

```
object instantiatedType =
   Activator.CreateInstance(typeToInstantiate,
   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
     System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance,
   null, new object[] {parameter}, null);
```

There are two issues this addresses:

- the `new object[] {parameter}` helps it handle the issue of passing an `object[]` as a **single** parameter of method that takes a `params object[]` argument
- the `BindingFlags` helps resolve the non-public constructor

(the two `null`s relate to the *binder*; the default binder behaviour is fine for what we want)

Comment: It seems like ` Activator.CreateInstance` can't determine the difference between two single-parameter constructors that accept different types...

Comment: This approach of running `Activator.CreateInstance()` really makes encapsulation irrelevant. Really nice one!

Answer (score 6):

You need to call [a different overload of `Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) that lets you pass a `nonPublic` or `BindingFlags` parameter.

I find all these `CreateInstance` overloads clumsy; what I prefer to do is:

1. Call `typeToInstantiate.GetConstructor()`, passing `BindingFlags.NonPublic`
2. Call `ConstructorInfo.Invoke`, passing it the constructor parameter

Answer (score 3):

change it to

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeToInstantiate,new object[] { parameter });
```

This is because your constructor also expects an object array and activator already splits it up into separate objects