# Activator.CreateInstance, gives Constructor on type 'SFImporterDLL.DtaRow' not found

Tags: vb.net, system.reflection

I'm reading rows from a file and creating an object for each one. Depending on a field in the row of data, I create one of a number of classes. If that data is missing or doesn't match in my Select, it defaults to DtaRow, the subclass of all of them. I do this...

```
Dim K As Object() = {DT, Key} 'DT is an instance of DtaTable, Key is a row number
RT = Dp.RowClassForTable(DT) ' translates DT.Name to namspace.class
DR = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(RT, K), DtaRow)
```

In this case, RT is being set to `MyProject.DtaRow`. The default constructor on DtaRow, which is also provided in all subclasses, is...

```
Friend Sub New(ByVal DTin As DtaTable, Optional Key As Integer = -1)
```

Everything seems right, all inputs are non-null and contain expected values. But I guess I have the syntax incorrect, because I get :

> Constructor on type 'SFImporterDLL.DtaRow' not found.

Is Optional causing an issue perhaps?

Comment: You're seeing a `MissingMethodException` because your constructor is `friend`. Changing it to `public` will allow your code to work. If it must be `friend`, then you might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077253/instantiating-a-constructor-with-parameters-in-an-internal-class-with-reflection

Comment: I cant get it to work with an optional param when omitted.  But since you use/know the type in order to cast the object created, why not just create it directly?

Comment: also, what is `RT` a Type or a string? (I'm guessing Type based on the overload used)