# How can I manually build one valid DragEventArgs object in order to call the Window_Drop() method?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm building one software integration with one old WPF application. This WPF application have an event handler for drop event:

```
public void Window_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   // Spaghetti code
}
```

The *Window_Drop* event take the dropped file, elaborate it and send the result to a web services.

My goal is use the current logic dropping a file inside a specific folder.

I wrote this code:

**Watcher class**

```
public class Watcher
    {
        public delegate void ActionDelegate(string fileName, string fullPath);
        private ActionDelegate Action;

        private readonly FileSystemWatcher _watcher;
        public Watcher(string path)
        {
            _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            _watcher.Path = path;
            _watcher.Created += _watcher_Created;
            _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        public void SubscribeOnCreate(ActionDelegate action)
        {
            Action = action;
        }

        private void _watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creato " + e.Name);
            Action(e.Name, e.FullPath, string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

**App.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application, ISingleInstanceApp
{
    private Watcher _watcher;

    public App()
    {
        _watcher = new Watcher(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Monitoraggio");
        _watcher.SubscribeOnCreate(LoadFile);
    }

    private void LoadFile(string fileName, string fullPath)
    {
        var droppedFile = new DragEventArgs(); // How can I build one DragEventArgs object with dropped file?
        var currentWindow = MainWindow.AppWindow; // this is a static reference of current MainWindow
        a.Window_Drop(this, droppedFile);
    }
}
```

How can I build one vali DragEventArgs manually?

Every suggestion is welcome,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an instance of the `DragEventArgs` class without using reflection since it has no `public` constructor defined.

What you should do is to refactor the `Window_Drop` event handler so that it takes the data that it needs from the `DragEventArgs` that gets created by the framework and then passes this data to a method of yours that you can also call from your `LoadFile` method.

So instead of trying to invoke the actual event handler, you call the same method as the event handler calls if you see what I mean.

The other, non-recommended, option would be to use reflection to create an instance of the `DragEventArgs` class:

[Instantiating a constructor with parameters in an internal class with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077253/instantiating-a-constructor-with-parameters-in-an-internal-class-with-reflection)

Comment: Just to add another restriction why it's not that trivial to create an instance of DragEventArgs. DragEvenArgs is marked as a sealed class.
So it was not intended to be derived from, thereby preventing you from creating a new subclass that you can actually instantiate.