# Mock third-party interface with return type that has readonly props & internal ctor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mocking, moq

I'm trying to mock a third-party interface that I'm using ([EventStore ClientAPI/IEventStoreConnection](https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/blob/feaaae634ad661f8f19221c569e669d73ea6e831/src/EventStore.ClientAPI/IEventStoreConnection.cs)), in particular this method:

```cs
Task<StreamEventsSlice> ReadStreamEventsForwardAsync(string stream, long start, int count, bool resolveLinkTos, UserCredentials userCredentials = null);
```

The problem I'm having is that the return type `StreamEventsSlice` has `readonly` fields and an `internal` constructor i.e.

```cs
public class StreamEventsSlice
{
    public readonly string Stream;
    //other similar fields

    internal StreamEventsSlice(string stream) //missing other fields
    {
        Stream = stream;
    }
}
```

In my test code I'm mocking the event store connection using `Moq`, setting up the `ReadStreamEventsForwardAsyncMethod`, and trying to set the return type like so:

```cs
var connection = new Mock<IEventStoreConnection>();
connection.Setup(s => s.ReadStreamEventsForwardAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<long>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<UserCredentials>())
    .ReturnsAsync(new StreamsEventSlice { props here });
```

But I can't set the properties, or call the constructor instead of that (I only actually need to set two properties)

I've tried making a stub that extends the original class, and returning that instead. Although I can hide the readonly properties I get an error on the class saying 'StreamEventsSlice does not have a constructor that takes 0 arguments'. Giving it a constructor doesn't work as I can't call the base ctor since it's internal.

How can I mock a method on an interface, when I can't instantiate the return type?

Comment: You can use reflection. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565747/9363973) shows you how to set the value of a private property. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/708976/9363973) show you how to instantiate an object that doesn't have a public constructor

Comment: Then wrap that 3rd party dependency behind an abstraction that you can control. This issue demonstrates the risks associated with tightly coupling to code you can't control. The designers of that 3rd party interface thought they were being clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MindSwipe linked two good answers, unfortunately I couldn't use [this one for constructing an object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/708976/6330878) as one of the parameters for the constructor was also set to internal. Instead I had to use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501740/6330878), and use their other suggestion to set the properties.

I kept most of mock setup code the same, other then adding and using the following method to instantiate `StreamEventsSlice`

```cs
internal StreamEventsSlice GetStreamEventSlice(ResolvedEvent[] events = null, bool isEndOfStream = true)
{
    events = events ?? new ResolvedEvent[0];
    var type = typeof(StreamEventsSlice);
    var slice = (StreamEventsSlice) FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type);
    type.GetField("Events").SetValue(slice, events);
    type.GetField("IsEndOfStream").SetValue(slice, isEndOfStream);

    return slice;
}
```