# Create a new instance of T without the new constraint

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, instantiation

If one wants to create a new instance of a generic, the [new constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) needs to be defined, like so:

```
public T SomeMethod<T>() where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Is it possible, using reflection, to create an instance of T without the new constraint, like so (contains  pseudocode):

```
public T SomeMethod<T>()
{
    if (T has a default constructor)
    {
        return a new instance of T;
    }
    else
    {
        return Factory<T>.CreateNew();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `a new instance of T` = `new T()'

Comment: Note - you can't satisfy constraints via `if` checked - even if you check that it *has* a constructor, you won't be able to call down into a method that *demands* the `T : new()` constraint, because the compiler *won't believe you*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `Activator.CreateInstance()` for this. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx for more information on how to use this method. Basically, what you do is:

```
var obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
```

You can verify whether it has a default constructor by using the `GetConstructors()` method:

```
var constructors = typeof(T).GetConstructors();
```

If you find a constructor that has zero parameters, you can use the `Activator.CreateInstance` method. Otherwise, you use the `Factory<T>.CreateNew()` method.

**EDIT:**

To find out directly whether a constructor without any parameters exist, you can use the following check:

```
if (typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
{
    // ...
```

Comment: just on the `GetConstructors()` thing - `typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)` is probably more specific - returns `null` or non-`null`.

Answer (score 13):

Generic methods with a `where T : new()` constraint implement `new T()` calls by invoking `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`. One interesting thing about this method is that it *doesn't include the constraint*, so if you are happy to defer the check until runtime, just use:

```
public T SomeMethod<T>() {
    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
}
```

which will *either* do exactly what `return new T()` *would* have done, or will raise a meaningful exception. Because it handles both the success and failure case, there is no real benefit in doing any additional checks, unless you wanted to do something obscure like *not using a constructor at all* (which can be done).

Comment: You said: _not using a constructor at all (which can be done)_. Can you please show how that can be done, I mean create instance without using constructor? I want the user of my method to not get null exception when they do `record.SomeColumn`, where `record` is a collection of columns of a db table, and `SomeColumn` is a column, AND there exists no record. Please note that I too don't have (and can't have) the `T : new()`

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ `System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` - note that an object created in this way can have *completely non-deterministic behaviour*; the typical use case for this is for serialization or ORM libraries when creating POCO/DTO records

Comment: Thanks very much. Just one more help please. Is it okay to create an object this way, and then initialize that manually using reflection? As I have already mentioned, when I get no record in DB (I am using Dapper, BTW), I want the returned object to be non-null, but all its properties having their respective default values. Also, can you please tell me where I can learn about the _completely non-deterministic behaviour_?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ by non-deterministic behaviour I mean simply: anything that the constructor would usually have done (like configuring private state): won't have happened. As for "is it OK" - that's massively contextual and depends on the type being created. For a POCO it'll usually work. If you try it with `SqlConnection` or something similar: expect it to fail

Comment: Mine is a POCO, so I am safe ;-) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The last sentence from Marc Gravell's answer (emphasis mine)

> ...unless you wanted to do something obscure like not using a constructor
>   at all (**which can be done**)

and from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313234/create-a-new-instance-of-t-without-the-new-constraint#comment85101658_17313431) of his, there is an alternative to achieve the same thing. I don't much know which is [better performance wise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162475/3375713), but honestly, I don't care. If you want to know, follow that link. There author shows a *hybrid* way.

Use [`System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Runtime_Serialization_FormatterServices_GetUninitializedObject_System_Type_) (old MSDN documentation [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
public static T SomeMethod<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    return (T)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(T));
}
```

Note the special care for `string`. Without that `GetUninitializedObject()` would fail. This is from MSDN on using this approach on strings:

> It does not create an uninitialized string, since creating an empty
>   instance of an immutable type serves no purpose.

It says nothing about why *it fails*, but more about why *it should fail*. Immediately after this there is another *Note* which goes like this:

> You cannot use the GetUninitializedObject method to create instances
>   of types that derive from the [ContextBoundObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.contextboundobject?view=netframework-4.7.1) class.