# Generic type whose type parameter is an abstract base class

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

Let's say I have a **base class** named `Animal` and two **derived classes** named `Lion` and `Tiger`. And I'd like to also have a **generic type** named `AnimalList<Animal>` to contain members of `Animal`. For example:

```cpp
var list = new AnimalList<Animal>();

list.Add(new Lion());
list.Add(new Tiger());
```

Very straightforward so far but there's a catch...I'd like the base class `Animal` to be `abstract`. That is, **I don't want to allow an instance of the base class to be created.** However, making the base class abstract not surprisingly results in error [CS0310](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h7h44y.aspx) (see a complete example below).

I did come up with a solution: Make the base class non-abstract as required and simply throw an exception from the default (parameterless) constructor:

```cpp
public Animal()
{
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

But this makes me feel a little uneasy. **Is there a better way?**

---

Here's a complete example that illustrates the scenario that I describe above:

```cpp
// public class Animal {}        // OK
public abstract class Animal {}  // 'abstract' keyword causes error 'CS0310'

public class Lion : Animal {}
public class Tiger : Animal {}

public class AnimalList<T> :
    Animal
    where T : Animal, new()
{
    public void Add(T animal) {}
}

class AnimalListDemo
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The following statement causes:
        // error CS0310 - 'Animal' must be a non-abstract type with a
        // public parameterless constructor in order to use it as
        // parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'AnimalList<T>'

        var list = new AnimalList<Animal>();

        list.Add(new Lion());
        list.Add(new Tiger());
    }
}
```

Comment: The `new()` constrains asks for a class with a callable default constructor, but abstract classed don't have one. The whole point of abstract classes is that you can't construct them after all. Your sample code works fine if you remove that constraint. In general I'd consider the `new()` constraint a bit of a code smell.

Comment: As @CodesInChaos suggests, its not the `abstract` keyword, its the `new()` constraint: http://rextester.com/LXDH46444

Comment: What's the benefit of a generic definition that is restricted to an abstract class anyways? why not just `class AnimalList : Animal, IList<Animal>`?

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Your comment got me on the right track. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21491344/1497596).

Comment: @LorentzVedeler - You make a good point. The pattern in my real code actually includes another level in the hierarchy: `abstract class AnimalList<Animal> : Animal, IList<Animal>` and `class ExtendedLionList : AnimalList<Lion>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `new()` constraint. It requires you to provide a class that can be instantiated through `new()` (which is what the requirement is all about), but an abstract class obviously can't do this.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx):

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. **To use the new constraint, the type cannot be abstract**.

Answer (score 2):

Is it absolutely necessary to have the `new()` constraint on the generic parameter? If you remove it, it will compile, at the cost of not allowing creating new instances of `T` within `AnimalList`.

Reason for that is that if you request the class to have a public, parameterless constructor, it cannot be abstract, because abstract classes are meant specifically to be non-creatable, but you're requesting the class to be creatable with the `new()`. As those requirements contradict each other, the compiler complains.

The solution seems to be rather a hack, and will not work either, because the derived class constructor will also call the base class constructor (instead of completely override it) and still throw the exception.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of my question, I asked:

> **Is there a better way?**

My conclusion from the helpful answers on this page: **Yes!**

In particular, in his comment to my question, @CodesInChaos said the following:

> In general I'd consider the `new()` constraint a bit of a code smell.

This got me searching for an alternative to the `new()` constraint. (I do indeed have the need to create instances of the generic type parameter in a base class within my class hierarchy.)

I found what I was looking for in this answer to [Create a new instance of T without the new constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17313274/1497596):

```cpp
var instanceOfT = new T(); // Before

var instanceOfT = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)); // After
```

This allowed me to drop the few `new()` constraints that I had in my source code. And finally, dropping the `new()` constraints allowed me to set an intermediate class to `abstract` as I desired.

Comment: I'd consider `Activator.CreateInstance` a bit of a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are allowed to be combined with the `new` constraint:

```
public interface IAnimal {}

public abstract class Animal : IAnimal {} 

public class AnimalList<T> where T : IAnimal, new() {}
```

However, your first line will still fail:

```
var list = new AnimalList<Animal>();
```

`AnimalList<Animal>` (or `AnimalList<IAnimal>`) is not a valid type because the given `T` can't be constructed. Are you sure [new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) is what you want?