# Create an instance of a class with no constructors?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

My app is a Windows Phone 8 app that uses the speech recognition library.  One object type in that class is **SpeechRecognitionResult**.  This class has no constructors or they are internal.  I want to create an object of this type so I can return design time data from a property in my view model that is of type *SpeechRecognitionResult*.  I found this SO post that seemed to have a solution:

[Creating instance of type without default constructor in C# using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390578/creating-instance-of-type-without-default-constructor-in-c-sharp-using-reflectio)

But I can't find the *FormatterServices* symbol anywhere so I can call *FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()*.  I do have *System.Reflection* and "System.Runtime.Serialization" included in my code file.  Does anyone know where I can find that method in my WP8 project?  If not, is there another way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to retrieve the internal/private constructor, and invoke it. It is another question if you should do this, since the constructor is internal/private *for a reason*, and this usually means that you shouldn't do it.

```
public class TestClass {
    private TestClass() { }
}

var t = typeof(TestClass);
var ci = t.GetConstructor(
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    new Type[0],
    null
);
var myTestClassObject = (TestClass)ci.Invoke(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Many times when classes don't have a constructor they aren't intended to be created directly. In the case of a `SpeechRecognitionResult` object these objects are a result of the call to `RecognizeSpeechToTextAsync`. You can find examples online but one simple example is:

```
var credentials = new SpeechAuthorizationParameters();
credentials.ClientId = "<YOUR CLIENT ID>";
credentials.ClientSecret = "<YOUR CLIENT SECRET>";
var sr = new SpeechRecognizer("en-US", credentials);

var speechResult = await sr.RecognizeSpeechToTextAsync();
```

In this example "speechResult" is of the type "SpeechRecognitionResult". From there you should be able to serialize the "Text" or alternate versions properties and use those in your front end. Hopefully this helps put you on the right track!

If you need further details, [reference MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434617.aspx).