# C# create constructor while running

Tags: c#, reflection

I started to read about reflection and I wonder, is there a way to create a constructor while the program is running. For example: Get class C and check if C got empty constructor, if not, create on and use it to create this instance.
The constructor might have parameters too.

How can I do that?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/390578/1997232) issue?

Comment: No you can't add a constructor to an existing class. But you can call private constructors or create a raw zero initialized instance, bypassing constructors using [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx)

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: You can either create an entire new class, icluding its constructor(s) via `System.Reflection.Emit` or call existing constructor via `System.Reflection`. You can't modify exusting class

Comment: CodesInChaos, how can i create a zero initialized instance?

Comment: @user2462683 `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`, check the question @Sinatr linked for an example.

Comment: @user2462683 You mean you need a instance without invoking the constructor? There is an answer but why do you need it?

Comment: I need it because Marshal.PtrToStructure need an empty constructor and i don't want to write it to each class.

Answer (score 4):

In the .NET world, you need to know quite some things.

1. When a class doens't have a constructor, the compiler adds a default public one without any parameters.

That means that when you have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age
    {
        get { return 10; }
    }
}
```

It can be instantiated like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person = new Person();
        Console.WriteLine(person.Age);
    }
}
```

This would produce the following output:

[image]

2. As soon as you create a constructor, the default public, parameterless one is not added by the compiler.

This means that when you change your person class to the following:

```
public class Person
{
    private Person() { }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return 10; }
    }
}
```

You're not able to instantiate the class using the new() keyword:

```
var person = new Person();
```

This would result in a compile error:

[image]

3. Through reflection, you can construct an object event if the constructor is private and/or does contain parameters.

That being said, your question is unclear because you would never need to create a constructor at runtime, because of the following:

- A class without a constructor has a constructor added by the compiler and can be constructed through reflection.
- A class with a constructor can be constructed through reflection.
- A class with an in-accesible constructed can be constructed through reflection.

Now, let's see how to construct classes using reflection using the 3 scenario's above:

- You have a class without a constructor.

  ```
  public class Person
  {
      public int Age
      {
          get { return 10; }
      }
  }
  ```

  Your instance can be created like:

  ```
  var instance = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person));
  ```
- You have a class with a public constructor

  ```
  public class Person
  {
      public Person() { }

      public int Age
      {
          get { return 10; }
      }
  }
  ```

  Your instance can be created just in the same way as above, nothing special is needed.

  ```
  var instance = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person));
  ```
- You have a class with a private constructor

  ```
  public class Person
  {
      private Person() { }

      public int Age
      {
          get { return 10; }
      }
  }
  ```

  Now your instance cannot be created in such an easy way.
  First, you need to get your ConstructorInfo:

  ```
  ConstructorInfo c = typeof(Person).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] {  }, null);
  ```

  With the code above, your requesting information about the constructors which are not public (BindingFlags.NonPublic).

  After you have retrieved it, you can construct your object like:

  ```
  var instance = (Person)c.Invoke(new object[] { });
  ```

Let's make it a bit more difficult with the following scenario's:

- You have a class with a public constructor that accepts parameters:

  ```
  public class Person
  {
      public Person(int age)
      {
          Age = age;
      }

      public readonly int Age;
  }
  ```

  The creation is still quite easy:

  ```
  var instance = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person), 15);
  ```

  You just need to pass all your parameters in the same way as they are defined in your constructor.
- You have a class with a private constructor that accepts parameters:

  ```
  public class Person
  {
      public Person(int age)
      {
          Age = age;
      }

      public readonly int Age;
  }
  ```

  Again, we'll need the ConstructorInfo object, but now we need to specify with types of parameters     are constructor is accepting. In the example above, this is an integer:

  ```
  ConstructorInfo c = typeof(Person).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(int) }, null);
  ```

  Now, you can create an object and as a last parameter you specify all the arguments to construct your object.

  ```
  var instance = (Person)c.Invoke(new object[] { 15 });
  ```

So, this was a very long post about reflection but I hope that I mde some things clear.
At least, it should be clear right now why you don't need to add a constructor at runtime in able to invoke an object.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new `Type` via `Reflection.Emit` but creating a constructor for existing type is not possible as constructors should be there in metadata of the type in the assembly. You need to declare the constructor upfront.

If you use `Mono.Cecil` you could add new constructor to a type, then save it in a new assembly(but that's different story).