# Create Dummy-instance for singleton

Tags: c#, reflection, mocking, singleton

I have a singleton-class that I want to mock for testing as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
    private readonly static MyClass _instance = new MyClass();
    public MyClass Instance { get { return this._instance; }}

    private MyClass() 
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

As the private constructor of `MyClass` has some heavy logic including reading some config-files I want to mock the singleton-instance for testing-purposes. However I can´t see any way on doing this as I can´t mark the property `Instance` virtual.

I think I have two oppourtunities, but I don´t know which fits better. The first one is making the (private) `DomeSomething`-method overridable (meaning `protected` and `virtual`) and create some dummy-implementation for it in a derived class (the mock). However modifying my class-structure for the sake of testing does not seem right to me.

The other way could be by using `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()` as suggested in [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390596/2528063). I´d simply create an instance without setting *any* of its members. Afterwards I could intialize *the members I need* by reflection using some simpler logic. Anyway this also seems quite crude to me.

Are there any other opportunities I have? Or do I have to chose between those two annoying ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is no really clean way to do this. You would either have to change the interface of the class or use tricks like reflection/FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject like you already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to try [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/docs).

Its solution for mocking singletons is uniquely easy, no changes in production code needed (your private methods still be private). Take a look on the example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var fakeSingleton = Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<MyClass>();

    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeSingleton.someFunction()).WillReturn(true);

    Assert.IsTrue(MyClass.Instance.someFunction());
 }
```

You are creating a fake by calling `Isolate.Fake.AllInstances<MyClass>()`, when setting behaviors you like, and it will be setted on the singleton's instance as well.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nice tool. Unfortunetaly its not for free, but I consider try its free trial.