# Can I use moq Mock<MyClass> to mock a class, not an interface?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Going through https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart, I see it Mock an interface.

I have a class in my legacy code which does not have an interface. When I `Mock<MyClass>`, I get the following exception:

> Additional information: Can not instantiate proxy of class: MyCompnay.Mylegacy.MyClass.

How can I use Moq to mock class from legacy code?

Comment: There's probably more to the error message that explains why Moq can't create the proxy.  If you include the class definition (at least the constructors) along with the test code that is using moq, you'll probably get an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock a class with no interface and no virtual methods in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356771/how-to-mock-a-class-with-no-interface-and-no-virtual-methods-in-c)

Comment: Show an example of the class. unless the class is sealed or has no virtual methods or properties then it should be able to be mocked.

Comment: In Moq you can't mock concrete classes, for doing so and testing legecy code you can use unit testing tools that support it, like Typemock.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It **is** possible to Mock concrete classes

```
[TestClass]
public class PlaceholderParserFixture
{

  public class Foo
  {
     public virtual int GetValue()
     {
        return 11;
     }
  }

  public class Bar
  {
     private readonly Foo _foo;

     public Bar(Foo foo)
     {
        _foo = foo;
     }

     public int GetValue()
     {
        return _foo.GetValue();
     }
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void MyTestMethod()
  {
     var foo = new Mock<Foo>();
     foo.Setup(mk => mk.GetValue()).Returns(16);
     var bar = new Bar(foo.Object);

     Assert.AreEqual(16, bar.GetValue());
  }

}
```

but,

- It must be a public class
- The method to be mocked must be virtual

The messages I got for:

Making the class internal

> Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.GeneratorException: Type MoqFixture+Foo is not public. Can not create proxy for types that are not accessible.

or, having a non-virtual method

> System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: mk => mk.GetValue()

do not match your `cannot instantiate` message, so something else seems to be wrong.

If you do not have a default constructor on the mocked object you can get that error message

e.g.

```
public class Foo
{

    private int _value;
    public Foo(int value)
    {
       _value = value;
    }

    public virtual int GetValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}
```

one can get around this by passing values into the Mock<> ctor

e.g.

```
var foo = new Mock<Foo>(MockBehavior.Strict, new object[] { 11 });
```

Comment: The class does not have to be public. The error message says something about "accessbile". Use `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]` and Moq can access your internals and it works.