# how to abrote WebClient call if no response is being revevived within specifc time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc action method. the code will loop through a list of servers and for each server it will make a call to a third party system using `WebClient()` call.

```
                        //loop started
   try
      {


        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient()) // call the Third Party API to get the account id 
        {

          string url = currentURL + "resources/" + ResourceID + "/accounts?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
          var json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

         }

      }
   catch (Exception)
      {
       c.ScanResult = "Call to Third Party system Failed ";
       scan.Description = scan.Description + "<span style='color:red'>" + c.ScanResult + "</span><br/>";

       repository.Save2();
       continue;
      }
                      //end of loop
```

currently i am facing a problem if that when the loop start it will be working well,, and the `WebClient()` call will work normally... but after successive `WebClient()` requests the method will hang and seems the `WebClient()` call will hang for some reasons (maybe a problem in the third party system), and the whole method execution will stop (never ends), so can any one adivce how i can force the `WebClient()` to continue execution if it does not receive any response within certain amount of time (for example 5 minutes)? as currently no exception will be raised and the loop will never ends ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Timeout property on a WebRequest, but not a WebClient

More info here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6994391/5367708

```
  private class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
        w.Timeout = 5 * 60 * 1000;
        return w;
    }
}
```

So you can override the WebClient class and then use the MyWebClient instead.

Comment: ok i see, but can you adivce how i can chnage my Webcleitn to be a WebReqeuest ?