# How To Correctly Use Jenkins PowerShell step to call Web API using Invoke-WebRequest or Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, jenkins, webapi, invoke-webrequest, invoke-restmethod

I am using **Jenkins**, in a **PowerShell** command step, to call a **Web API** service. I am calling the service using [**Invoke-WebRequest**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest).

This service call has to be in Jenkins, because I need to do it only if other Jenkins jobs have completed successfully.

*The service can run for several hours.  If I don't have the **TimeoutSec** parameter, then the step completes with a timeout, before the Web API has completed. If I have the parameter with a large value, such as 36000, then the Web API completes normally, but the step goes on for 10 hours. The other parameters have no relation to this issue.*

**I am seeking a good way to have the Jenkins step complete as soon as the Web API completes, not earlier and not later.**

```
try
{ 
    $url = "https://ourserver.com/modules/OurService"
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get -TimeoutSec 36000 -UseBasicParsing  
}
catch 
{    
    $err=$_.Exception  
    Write-Host '-----------------------'
    Write-Host $err        
    Write-Host '-----------------------'  
    exit -1
}
exit 0
```

Comment: Can you add more information about your job definition in Jenkins? Maybe try setting the `MaxServicePointIdleTime`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34139528/7411885

Comment: How do you determine that the "Web API completes normally"? Maybe it just does its job, but doesn't actually return a response?

Comment: Cpt.Whale - this job only contains two steps: Build Trigger and a Build. I have no problem defining a fixed period after which a timeout happens. I just don't know how to exit exactly when the Web API is complete (and not before).

Comment: zett42 - my Web API is returning a 200 (OK) when success (I am pretty confident is doing that since PostMan indicates this). Should I be checking for a 200 value in the $response somehow? It seems to be a sync call to Invoke-WebRequest that never gets to the 'exit 0' when complete.

Comment: If `$response` is getting set to 200, the very next thing *should* already be `exit`. If the request literally took the whole timeout time, then the command should throw a timeout error instead of exiting normally.

Comment: Isn't this a bug in `Invoke-WebRequest`? Because there are 3 options: 1) end successfully, 2) end with an error 3) end after timeout if the request is still [_pending_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2#parameters). But, if the request is or has been processed already the 3rd option should be completely out of play, shouldn't it?

Comment: @MikeDev Why don't you just use the [HTTP Request Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/)?

Comment: Cpt. Whale - the response is definitely getting set to 200 within the web-api code. The request (Invoke-WebRequest) is taking the whole time period and is throwing a timeout error when TimeoutSec is elapsed.

Comment: Gerold Broser - I agree, I think this is a bug in Invoke-WebRequest.  Noah Helmer - I will look into Http Request Plug-In as an option. Thanks all.

Comment: @GeroldBroser that is correct, but the Http request plugin offers an easy, more readable alternative for the Powershell step, and is much easier to integrate into his Jenkins pipeline - and therefore should be considered as an efficient alternative.

Comment: @NoamHelmer You are too fast. :) I removed my previous comment less than a minute after I wrote it since I wanted to check if there is a HTTP Request step on a project's config page.

Comment: The webapi that is being called is very long running (multiple hours). I think that adds a layer of complexity. I tried HTTP Request step but that step never completed (after running overnight). Also, it took a very long time to be able to cancel the very long running job. I am back to working with Invoke-WebRequest (for now). One thing I am doing differently: checking "Stop On Errors" on the Build Step.

Comment: @NoamHelmer And there is: https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request/#configure-build-step-in-your-jenkins-job.

Comment: Is using an **Exceute shell** build step with [`curl`](https://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/ssen/src/curl-7.11.1/docs/curl.html) or [`wget`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) an option?

Comment: Powershell, Invoke-WebRequest: the code within the webapi completed, but Jenkins job never did, but I was at least able to cancel the job. HTTP Request: never completed and Jenkins had to be restarted to cancel the job. I think the issue is that my webapi is so long running (1-2 hours) that it is in the realm of the unusual. I am going to next look at options such as curl, wget, Groovy or something in an Execute Shell step. Thanks all for your feedback and suggestions thus far.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach, and I think I am closer to where I want to be now...

I decided to go with **Invoke-RestMethod**

*A strange issue remains: when my long running service is called and that service completes, I fall down into the catch, but the Exception has nothing in it. Per the logs for my service, I know the service completed successfully. So, at this point I am treating it as successful.*

```
try
{
  $url = "https://ourserver.com/modules/OurService"
  $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Get -TimeoutSec 18000
  $response  
  Write-Host 'Exit with success'
  exit 0
}
catch
{
  if (($_.Exception) -and ($_.Exception.Response))
  {
    $respStream = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($respStream)
    $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
    $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd() | ConvertFrom-Json
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------' 
    'Error Message:'
    $responseBody.Message
    $_.Exception
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    exit -1
  }
  else
  {
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------' 
    'Got to catch, but no exception (we should not have gotten to "catch" area, possible PowerShell bug)'  
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
    exit 0
  }
  
}
```