# extend time out on post form in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, http-post

I am using a post function in my code but sometimes it gives a timeout, long duration is not the problem but I need the code to wait on the response.
Using this code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                formData.Add(Hdata, "data", "data");
                formData.Add(Hclient, "client", "client");
                formData.Add(Hpage, "page", "page");
                formData.Add(Hloop, "loop", "loop");
                formData.Add(Hproperties, "properties", "properties");
                formData.Add(Hrelation, "user", "user");
                formData.Add(Hbinary, "binary", "binary");
                requestMessage.Content = formData;

                //client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);;
                var response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
                {
                    if (sr != null)
                    {
                        json = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Tried in the past many things but non of them worked, can somebody advise me what to do?

UPDATE: forgot this is an Xamarin Visual Studio project

Answer (score 0):

You can set this value in web.config.  For example, to change the timeout for one specific page:

```
<location path="somefile.aspx">
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180"/>
</system.web>
```

See http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx for more details.
or 
You can check this answer
[How to change the timeout on a .NET WebClient object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789627/how-to-change-the-timeout-on-a-net-webclient-object)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry its an Xamarin project

Comment: then i do not know so sorry