# Why python request working but C# request not working?

Tags: c#, python, postman

First, i try to post the script in PostMan tool.

```
{"AO":"ECHO"}
```

It working fine. Then i'm writing this request in C# but it not working.
And more i wrote the request again in Python, and it working well.
But my project is in Microsoft C#. I dont want to run script Python in C# at all.

==== Python =========

```
import httplib
import json
import sys

data = '{"AO":"ECHO"}'
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Connection": "Keep-Alive" }
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("http://10.10.10.1",1040)
conn.request("POST", "/guardian", data, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()

print response.status, response.reason
print response.msg
```

==== C# ============

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://10.10.10.1:1040/guardian");

            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {

                string json = "{\"AO\":\"ECHO\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }
```

I try to put "ContentLength" but it still timeout exception.
And i try to using RestSharp, it's not timeout but return null.
Any one please help...

```
            var client = new RestClient("http://10.10.10.1:1040/guardian");
            var request = new RestRequest();

            request.Method = Method.POST;
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.Parameters.Clear();
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddBody(new { AO = "ECHO" });

            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;
```

Please help me,
I dont understand why it working fine in python.
But why it not working in C#.
I try to find many request in C# but it got error exception with timeout.

Comment: Is your problem similar like this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789627/how-to-change-the-timeout-on-a-net-webclient-object) ?

Comment: Dear @Shankfk,
There are not the same of my problem.
It testing on my network server. It take time just 3 second to execute this.
And it working very well in python script as detail above.
But in C# it not working at all, it return error exception timeout.
However i try to change timeout.

Comment: Do Python and C# use the same encoding?

Comment: I'm new with python, that make me stuck with it

Comment: Can you post the server code?  Or make the server accessible from the internet and post the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Python will automatically add Content-Length http header.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httpconnection-objects

I think you might have to set this header manually in C#.

```
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = json.length;
```

Depending on the server, you may have to set UserAgent as well.

```
httpWebRequest.UserAgent=".NET Framework Test Client";
```

Comment: Hi Veener,
It's still got the same error occurs. Seem not work with that way.

Comment: At this point I would use fiddler or Wireshark to inspect the http traffic and compare the request and response going to the server between the two languages.