# Getting "An exception occurred during a WebClient request" while download the large file using webclient

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm getting above error while downloading the 4.5GB size text file using webclient in c#.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(DownloadFromURIpath, DownloadTOPath);
```

I split the file in half, and now it is downloading successfully.There appears to be a problem with importing files over 3 GB.
Is there any limit for webclient to download the file ?
Anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks,
Kavin.S

Comment: Do you get a message with that exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either `wc.DownloadFileAsync()` or follow what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6994391/4813148)