# How to make webclient download file again if failed?

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to download a list of links of images to my server (Up to 40 links) using foreach.

In my case sometimes the link exists but I don't know why it's going to catch and cancel the download of the next link. Maybe it needs to wait for a little? because when I debug the app I see that the link was the application skipped and went to catch was available but sometimes it's open after few seconds in my browser so the response time from the server I trying to download sometimes need more time to load and open the link.

```
   string newPath = "~/data/" + model.PostID + "/" + name + "/";

   //test1 is a list of links
                foreach (var item1 in test1)
                {

                    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(item1) as HttpWebRequest; request.Method = "HEAD";
                    try
                    {
                        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                        {
                            var webClient = new WebClient();
                            string path = newPath + i + ".jpg";
                            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(item1), Server.MapPath(path));
                            string newlinks = "https://example.com/data/" + chapter.PostID + "/" + name + "/" + i + ".jpg";
                            allimages = allimages + newlinks + ',';
                            response.Close();
                            i++;

                        }
                    }

                    catch
                    {                           
                        break;
                    }



                }
```

**Now my main goal is to fix this issue but as I saw in debugging:**

1. The Images Links I'm trying to download exists
2. Sometimes Need More Time to response

So How I can fix this ? when download cancel and a link exists, what I should do?

Comment: Keep track of failed downloads, and try them again (i.e. an extra loop).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the timeout on a .NET WebClient object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789627/how-to-change-the-timeout-on-a-net-webclient-object)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example:

```
    class WebClientUtility : WebClient
    {
        public int Timeout { get; set; }

        public WebClientUtility() : this(60000) { }

        public WebClientUtility(int timeout)
        {
            this.Timeout = timeout;
        }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request != null)
            {
                request.Timeout = Timeout;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }

    //
    public class DownloadHelper : IDisposable
    {
        private WebClientUtility _webClient;
        private string _downloadUrl;
        private string _savePath;
        private int _retryCount;

        public DownloadHelper(string downloadUrl, string savePath)
        {
            _savePath = savePath;
            _downloadUrl = downloadUrl;

            _webClient = new WebClientUtility();

            _webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += ClientOnDownloadFileCompleted;
        }


        public void StartDownload()
        {
            _webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(_downloadUrl), _savePath);
        }

        private void ClientOnDownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                _retryCount++;

                if (_retryCount < 3)
                {
                    _webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(_downloadUrl), _savePath);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _retryCount = 0;
                Console.WriteLine($"successfully download: # {_downloadUrl}  to  # {_savePath}");
            }
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _webClient.Dispose();
        }
    }

    //
    class Program
    {

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var downloadUrl = $@"https://example.com/mag-{i}.pdf";
                var savePath = $@"D:\DownloadFile\FileName{i}.pdf";

                DownloadHelper downloadHelper = new DownloadHelper(downloadUrl, savePath);

                downloadHelper.StartDownload();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

to fix timeout problem you can create a derived class and set the timeout property of the base WebRequest class and
for retry you can use the DownloadFileCompleted event of the WebClient and implement your retry pattern there

Answer (score 0):

You're using the async version of `'DownloadFileAsync'`. However you're not `awaiting` the call, that leaves a mess with unpredicted behaviour.

Make your method `async` and then use this:

```
await webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(item1), Server.MapPath(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

This Solved my case:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(item1), Server.MapPath(path));
                });
```