# How to add timeout and retry to url call in C#?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I have a `.tgz` file that I need to download given a url inside a `Testing` folder. I am able to download the `.tgz` file successfully from the url using `WebClient`.

Below is my code:

```
private void DownloadTGZFile(string url, string fileToDownload)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(url + fileToDownload, "Testing/configs.tgz");
    }
}
```

I wanted to see on how can I add a timeout to this call so that if url doesn't respond back within a particular time then it should timeout but it can retry for 3 times and then give up. Also I wanted to see on how can I use `HttpClient` here instead of `WebClient` considering it is an older BCL class and not recommended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the timeout on a .NET WebClient object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789627/how-to-change-the-timeout-on-a-net-webclient-object)

Comment: For the retry part of the question check out https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To download a file with `HttpClient` you can do:

```
// Is better to not initialize a new HttpClient each time you make a request, 
// it could cause socket exhaustion
private static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient()
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
};

public async Task<byte[]> GetFile(string fileUrl)
{
    using (var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(fileUrl))
    {
        // Throws an exception if response status code isn't 200
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    }
}
```

[For more details about socket exhaustion with HttpClient](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

As you see, to define a timeout for the `Http` call you should set a timeout while creating a new `HttpClient`.

---

To implement a retry policy for the previous code, I would install [Polly NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly) and then:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetFile(string fileUrl)
{
    return await Policy
       .Handle<TaskCanceledException>() // The exception thrown by HttpClient when goes in timeout
       .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: 3, sleepDurationProvider: i => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
       .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
       {
           using (var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(fileUrl))
           {
               // Throws an exception if response status code isn't 200
               httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
               return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
           }
       });
}
```

In this case I defined a retry of 3 times with an interval of 300 milliseconds between each tentative. Also note that I didn't defined the retry for every kind of `Exception`, because if - for example - you put an invalid `URL`, retrying is nonsense.

At the end, if you want to save that byte array to a file, you can just do:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"MyPath\file.extension", byteArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It makes sense now and I understand how to use timeout on HttpClient in a better way now. In your example you are returning `byte[]` so how can I download this file (.tgz file) in a folder? In my case I need to download the file from url in a particular folder. Is this possible here?

Comment: I added how to save the file at the end of the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function with no dependencies to external libraries. It works for any file size.

***EDIT***  Version to progapate the `TaskCanceledException`.

```
public async Task<bool> DownloadFileAsync(string url,
    string destinationFile,
    TimeSpan timeout,
    int maxTries = 3,
    CancellationToken token = default)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = timeout })
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < maxTries; i++, token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested())
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url, token);
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    continue;

                var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                using (var outputStream = new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    await responseStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream, 8 * 1024, token);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException)
            {
                //ignore
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forgot the `await` before the `Task.WaitAny(getTask);`?

Comment: Propagating cancellation by a special return value is unconventional. The [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) way is to throw an `OperationCanceledException`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias this function is not async, please check the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitany?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WaitAny_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's not asynchronous indeed. Why don't you use the `Task.WhenAny`, to avoid blocking the thread?

Comment: Checking the `token.IsCancellationRequested` results to inconsistent behavior. I suggest to use the `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` instead.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I've removed the first function to avoid confusions and unconventional code and I updated the second one. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Don't initialize your HttpClient every time you call the DownFileAsync method. Instead make it globally static like Francesco's answer above (or even better even use HttpClientFactory to create the HttpClient instance). Otherwise you risk socket exhaustion (also mentioned in Francesco's answer)