# c# make my a specific line to timeout after x seconds c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task, synchronous

I have a line in C# which does not work very reliable and does not time out at all and runs for infinity.

to be more precise i am trying to check the connection to a proxy WebClient.DownloadString

I want it to timeout after 5 seconds without making the full method asynchronous

so the code should be like this:

```
bool success = false

do_this_for_maximum_5_seconds_or_until_we_reach_the_end
{
WebClient.DownloadString("testurl");
success = true;
}
```

it will try to download testurl and after it did download it it will set success to true. If DownloadString takes more than 5 seconds, the call is canceled, we do not reach the the line where we set success to true, so it remains false and i know that it field.

The thread will remain frozen while we try to DownloadString, so the action is not taking parallel. The ONLY difference to a normal line would be that we set a timeout after 5 seconds

Please do not suggest alternatives such as using HttpClient, because i need a similar codes also for other places, so i simply want a code which will run in a synchronous application (i have not learned anything about asynchronus programing therefore i would like to avoid it completely)

my approach was like suggested by Andrew Arnott in this thread
[Asynchronously wait for Task<T> to complete with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)

however my issue is, I am not exactly sure what type of variable "SomeOperationAsync()" is in his example (i mean it seems like a task, but how can i put actions into the task?), and the bigger issue is that VS wants to switch the complete Method to asynchronos, but i want to run everything synchronous but just with a timeout for a specific line of code.

In case the question has been answered somewhere kindly provide a link

Thank you for any help!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789627/how-to-change-the-timeout-on-a-net-webclient-object

Comment: that solution uses WebRequest and not webclient. besides that i asked not to add a timeout parameter but c# to end this task by itself after x seconds so i can apply it for other issues like this one

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `WebClient` and not the newer `HttpClient`? Although it is asynchronous, you can synchronously wait on it along with a timed cancellation token, which will bounce you out after the timeout.

Comment: i need to check if a proxy server is working. the proxy requires authentication which i do not know how to set up. Besides that i am working on another project with Selenium where I have the same problem when loading a site. the method iteslf does not have a timeout mechanism so i need to set it up externaly. I could maybe find a work around for this case with httpclient/webclient but as i said in the original post, this problem happend a few times for me with other comands

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
var downloadString =
    Observable
        .Using(() => new WebClient(), wc => Observable.Start(() => wc.DownloadString("testurl")))
        .Select(x => new { success = true, result = x });

var timeout =
    Observable
        .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
        .Select(x => new { success = false, result = (string)null });
        
var operation = Observable.Amb(downloadString, timeout);

var output = await operation;

if (output.success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(output.result);
}
```

The first observable downloads your string. The second sets up a timeout. The third, uses the `Amb` operator to get the result from which ever of the two input observables completes first.

Then we can `await` the third observable to get its value. And then it's a simple task to check what result you got.