# I want to download a file using C#. But I am getting error "The operation time out."

Tags: c#, webclient

I am using WebClient to download a file from this URL
https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/var/C_VAR1_16112023_1.DAT

But I am getting error

> The operation time out.

```
string file_ = "https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/archives/nsccl/var/C_VAR1_16112023_1.DAT";
string path_ = "D:\Span4\Data\NSEVAR.Dat";

WebClient wc_ = new WebClient();
try
{
    wc_.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Other");
    wc_.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/pdf");
    wc_.DownloadFile(file_, path_);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error in VAR File Download " + ex.Message);
}
```

I have used the code. It works fine for file download from other websites. But the above mentioned URL is  not working

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Check this question [Timeout in WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789627/how-to-change-the-timeout-on-a-net-webclient-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line:

```
wc_.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Other");
```

And try again. I think the server is not recognizing "Other" as a valid UserAgent and for this reason the request is timing out.