# Extending HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

```
class AdvancedWebRequest : HttpWebRequest {
    private static readonly ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(AdvancedWebRequest));

    public AdvancedWebRequest(string url, CookieContainer cookies = null) {
        Create(url);
        UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22";
        Referer = Address.AbsoluteUri;

        if (cookies == null) {
            CookieContainer = Program.request.CookieContainer;
        } else {
            CookieContainer = cookies;
        }
    }
}
```

This is something I want to do, so basically get the HttpWebRequest with some variables already set, so I must not set them always myself.

Getting error:

```
'System.Net.HttpWebRequest.HttpWebRequest()' is obsolete: 'This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.' \Extensions\AdvancedWebRequest.cs   14  10
```

Any suggestions, can't `HttpWebRequest` be really extended?

Comment: Do you really need to inherit the HttpWebRequest Class? For some work, I created some functions for making HttpWebRequests easier, maybe its useful for you: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4347248

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls : it would be really good to inherit from it because from `WebRequest` I can't set `cookies`, `referer`, `useragent` at all.

Comment: Ok then you could try extension Methods msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Comment: @Tearsdontfall : This is nice feature I didn't know about, you can post it as answer because im sure someone will like that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not inherit from`HttpWebRequest` but you can inherit from `WebRequest`

Check the answers from the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400565/is-there-any-way-to-inherit-a-class-without-constructors-in-net).

Answer (score 3):

You could use Extension Methods like this:

```
public static DoRequest(this HttpWebRequest req){
//do something
}
```

and then you can call this method like this:

```
webrequest.DoRequest();
```

For more infos, look at the MSDN Page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx