# Slightly non-trivial data structure: is XmlSerializer right for me?

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer, xml-deserialization

I'm currently using `XmlSerializer` to, surprisingly enough :), handle de/serialization of my data structures - I find it wonderfully simple to use, but at the cost of flexibility. At the moment, I'm using it for a tree-based structure; since `XmlSerializer` doesn't handle cyclic structures, I've added `[XmlIgnore]` to my `Parent` property, and do a post-deserialization iteration over the tree to fix up node parents.

Is there a better way to handle this using `XmlSerializer`, or would it be better to rewrite the code using `XmlReader/XmlWriter`? I suppose implementing `IXmlSerializable` would work, but it seems like a fair amount of work, while still retaining the cons of `XmlSerializer`.

The current post-deserialization step is OK, but I'm adding a data structure that has to be serialized to a separate XML file: basically a flat list of items that need a Parent property referencing a node from the previous tree structure. This would require yet a post-deserialization step, as well as keeping both a Parent attribute as well as as ParentId (or some trickery) in the new data structure.

So, any smart (and non-fragile) ideas? Or `XmlReader/XmlWriter` it is?

### Solution

`DataContractSerializer` turned out to be a pretty decent solution, with pretty much the same simplicity as XmlSerializer. I opted not to use the automatic cycle handling but instead defining and [OnDeserialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) decorated method to handle setting the parent node; that way, the generated XML is standard-conforming.

One thing that confused me for a while was that I got crashes on some properties after deserializing, with the backing members set to null - couldn't figure out how this was possible since the backing members were definitely initialized in all possible constructors. Debugging showed constructors were never called, and after some googling I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076730/datacontractserializer-doesnt-call-my-constructor) with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try binary serialization  (BinarySerializer or DataContractSerializer), which I think handles cyclic graphs somewhat better, at the cost of not having a human-readable representation of the data. Alternatively, you can try the SoapFormatter as detailed [here](http://www.diranieh.com/NETSerialization/BinarySerialization.htm).

Comment: thanks - DataContractSerializer solved a lot of my woes. Funny thing, though: it seems my constructors aren't called when using it :-s

Comment: Ah, I see the constructor-skipping is by design; [OnDeserializing], here we go.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataContractSerializer`. Mark your classes with `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]`.