# Datacontract exception. Cannot be serialized

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have the following WCF DataContract:

```
[DataContract]
public class Occupant
{
    private string _Name;
    private string _Email;
    private string _Organization;
    private string _Badge;

    public Occupant(string name, string badge, string organization)
    {
        Name = name;
        Badge = badge;
        Organization = organization;
    }

    public Occupant(string name, string badge)
    {
        Value = name;
        Key = badge;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Key
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _Badge; }
        set { _Badge = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return _Email; }
        set { _Email = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Organization
    {
        get { return _Organization; }
        set { _Organization = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Badge
    {
        get { return _Badge; }
        set { _Badge = value; }
    }
}
```

When I try to access this service via web browser (it is hosted on IIS), I am getting this error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'MyNamespace.Occupant' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.

One of my methods is returning a `List` of type `Occupant`. Would this be causing it?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Because you have provided one or more initializing constructors, you will also need to add a parameterless (default) constructor.

i.e. You need to add:

```
[DataContract]
public class Occupant
{
    // *** Needed only for Serialization
    public Occupant() {}
    ...
```

This is because the [default constructor disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792207/why-does-the-default-parameterless-constructor-go-away-when-you-create-one-with) when you add an explicit constructor.

[The issue isn't with the method returning `List<Occupant>`, since methods aren't serialized).]

Comment: Despite the error, its moot whether DCS actually needs any constructor at all - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178645/how-does-wcf-deserialization-instantiate-objects-without-calling-a-constructor

Comment: Do we need a public parameterless constructor? Or private parameterless constructor will also work fine?

Comment: @VCD Private parameter-less constructor works. Just tried on .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: I believe this is wrong if the serialization is done by DataContractSerializer ,as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076730/datacontractserializer-doesnt-call-my-constructor
and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/august/service-station-serialization-in-windows-communication-foundation

Answer (score 9):

Try adding an empty constructor.  Often times that will set off the serializer.

Answer (score 5):

You need a default parameterless constructor. I don't ever plan to actually use mine, so I added a summary for IntelliSense and throw a run-time exception to keep it from being used.

```
/// <summary>
/// parameterless default constructor only for serialization
/// </summary>
public MyClass() { throw new NotImplementedException("parameterless default constructor only for serialization"); }
```

Comment: Serialization uses reflection to invoke constructor. So make it private to keep from beeing used.

Answer (score 2):

You should add an empty parameter constructor to your datacontract class

Answer (score 2):

When you have NO setter by default, do these steps:

1. Add parametreless constructor;
2. And add *private set* at least.

This helps me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be because `_Email` is not initialized.  You could set [`EmitDefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue.aspx) to `false` and see if that helps:

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public string Email
{
```