# Cannot instantiate class containing user-defined type

Tags: c++

I have a solid understanding of Java, but i'm trying to learn c++ to make a game and because I think c++ is a better language. But i'm having some problems with c++.

```
#ifndef RENDER_H
#define RENDER_H

#include "shader.h"
class Render
{

public: 
    Render();
protected:
private:
    Shader shader;
};

#endif
```

`Shader` is a class with a string constructor, just declaring it in this class causes an error. If I remove the constructor for `Shader` I don't get the error.

`Error: render.cpp:3:16: error: no matching function for call to 'Shader::Shader()'`

```
class Shader
{
public:
  Shader(const std::string& fileName);
  void Bind();
  void Update(const Transform& transform, const Camera& camera);

virtual ~Shader();
```

Comment: You should show the code for `Shader` (at least it's construction logic and the implementation of your `Render` constructor. It sounds like you might not have a default constructor and therefore you need to 1) Add a default constructor or 2) Properly use the initiailzer list in the `Render` constructor to instantiate the `Shader` object.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE]. It would also be useful to say what error you get.

Comment: @AlanStokes It states the error is a call to a missing default constructor for the `Shader` class.

Comment: The error is in a function you haven't shown us. See [MCVE].

Comment: You've declared the default constructor `Shader()`; have you defined it anywhere? Your compiler error indicates that you haven't.

Comment: @AlanStokes i added the default constructor but i get this error. **render.cpp:2: undefined reference to `Shader::Shader()'**

Comment: Don't change the question in a way that invalidates already posted answers.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Righto...

Comment: @R_Kapp Sorry, didn't realise question had been changed.

Comment: @user Another error in `render.cpp`? **Maybe that file is relevant.**

Answer (score 3):

`shader` is a class member of `Render`. When instantiating a `Render` object, the `Shader` object needs to be constructed along the way. Since it doesn't provide a default c'tor, it cannot be constructed (that's what the error message is telling you).

To work around this, either provide a default c'tor for `Shader`<sup>1)</sup>, or use an initializer list for `Render`s c'tor:

```
Render::Render() : shader("foo") {}
```

or

```
Render::Render(const std::string& shaderFilename) : shader(shaderFilename) {}
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Note: The compiler generates a default c'tor in case there aren't any c'tors defined. That's why removing `Shader`s custom c'tor appears to solve the issue.*

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies within the `Render` constructer (not shown in your question). Because your class `Render` has a member variable `Shader` which only has a single constructor (taking a `std::string` parameter), you **must explicitly call that constructor** in your constructor initializer list:

```
Render::Render()
: shader("MyRenderShader"); // construct the Shader
{
}
```

> If I remove the constructor for Shader I don't get the error.

Note that when you remove you `Shader` constructor, the compiler then [generates a default constructor for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792207/why-does-the-default-parameterless-constructor-go-away-when-you-create-one-with?rq=1), which means you don't need to explicitly call the constructor in `Render` (although you should).

Answer (score 0):

This your description

> Shader is a class with a string constructor, just declaring it in this
>   class causes an error. If I remove the constructor for Shader I don't
>   get the error

describes the problem. If you do not explicitly call the constructor of class Shader in the mem-initializer list of the constructor Render then the compiler tries to call the default constructor for data member `Shader shader;` . However it is not declared and the compiler issues an error.

Either call the constructor of class Shader in the mem-initializer list of the constructor Render specifying an argument or define the default constructor of the class Shader.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you didn't provide the string to Shader constructor in the Render constructor. You Render constructor needs to do something like this:

```
Render::Render()
   : shader("This is the string parameter of the shader")
{}
```

But as I can see that your Shader is virtual class, you most likely actually want to have the shader polymorphic. In such case you actually need to store is as a pointer and perhaps provide the actual implementation to the Render constructor, something like:

```
class Render
{

public: 
    Render(Shader *p_shader = NULL)
       : shader(p_shader)
    {}

    ~Render()
    { delete shader; }
protected:
private:
    Shader *shader;
};
```

And either disable copy construction and assignment or provide them as well and ensure copying the shader there to avoid double free on destruction.

Better yet to use std::unique_ptr or even std::shared_ptr (with shared_ptr you can use the compiler generated copy and assignment).

As you declare Java background, remember the equivalent of Java reference is the pointer in C++, i.e. the Java code:

```
Shader shader = new Shader();
```

translates in C++ to:

```
Shader *shader = new Shader();
```

(and no garbage collection is available, that's why to use smart pointers).