# Is a blank constructor required for WCF [DataContract] classes? Why?

Tags: c#, wcf, constructor

I was told by someone that a blank constructor was required for serializable objects that included getters and setters, such as below:

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }

    public Item() {}

    public Item(string description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

And the reason this was told me was that this allowed for construction of objects using the setter. However, I have found that the Item when defined like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Item
{
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }

    public Item(string description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Can be constructed without calling the constructor, when made available as a proxy class via a WCF service reference:

```
Item item = new Item {description = "Some description"};
```

Questions:

1. What exactly is that block of code I'm writing after declaring `new
   Item`
2. Is a blank constructor required for [DataContract] classes? If so, what does this blank constructor do?

I have found that I can't create an object without the constructor if the class is NOT a proxy class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What exactly is that block of code I'm writing

```
Item item = new Item {description = "Some description"};
```

Is equal and gets compiled to:

```
Item item = new Item();
item.description = "Some description";
```

So it requires a parameterless constructor. If the class doesn't have one, but has a parameterized one, you must use that one:

```
Item item = new Item("Some description");
```

Using named parameters, it would look like this:

```
Item item = new Item(description: "Some description");
```

You can still combine that with the object initializer syntax:

```
var item = new Item("Some description")
{
    Foo = "bar"
};
```

> Is a blank constructor required for [DataContract] classes?

Yes. The default serializer, DataContractSerializer, [doesn't use reflection to instantiate a new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076730/datacontractserializer-doesnt-call-my-constructor), [but still requires a parameterless constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077121/datacontract-exception-cannot-be-serialized).

If it can't find a parameterless constructor, it can't instantiate the object. Well, it can, but it doesn't. So if you were to actually use this `Item` class in a service operation:

```
public void SomeOperation(Item item)
{
}
```

Then WCF will throw an exception once you invoke this operation from a client, because the serializer can't find a parameterless constructor on `Item`.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely don't have a parameterless constructor for Item in my service that is consumed via a service reference. Does the proxy class get generated with a blank constructor automatically?

Comment: If a class doesn't contain a constructor at all, a parameterless one is generated automatically (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: On my service I've defined `Item` with a single constructor. On my client I add a service reference to that service, get a proxy class for `Item`, and can create instances of `Item` via  constructor with no argument (using the shorthand method)... Why?

Comment: Because [on the client a class with only the properties is generated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316118/constructor-in-wcf-datacontract-not-reflected-on-client), without constructors or methods (unless you reference the assembly containing the data contracts and opt to reuse the types when generating the client, but that's another story). If you use `Item` as a service operation parameter (`IService1.Foo(Item item)`), then that will blow up at runtime when you invoke that operation, because the serializer can't find a parameterless constrctor on `Item` at the service side.

Comment: That answers my question. I would guess since `Item` doesn't have a blank constructor there are use-cases that would cause exceptions on the service... But that's a question for another time. Thanks very much

Comment: `Yes. The serializer uses reflection to instantiate a new instance, and does so using the parameterless constructor.` That is not true. In WCF some black magic is used to create instances of objects. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076730/datacontractserializer-doesnt-call-my-constructor

Comment: @Jehof great addition, thanks. I knew that somewhere in the back of my head, yet WCF still requires a parameterless constructor to exist. Updated the answer.