# How is this field null?

Tags: c#

I'm getting a null exception, but the field was initialized as an empty list. So how could it be null?

The error occurs on the second line in this method (on _hydratedProperties):

```
protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    string propertyName = GetPropertyName(expression);

    if (!this._hydratedProperties.Contains(propertyName)) { this._hydratedProperties.Add(propertyName); }
}
```

And this is how the field is declared:

```
public abstract class EntityBase<TSubclass> : INotifyPropertyChanged where TSubclass : class
{
    private List<string> _hydratedProperties = new List<string>();
```

This is how it's set:

```
    public Eta Eta
    {
        get { return this._eta; }

        set
        {
            this._eta = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.Eta);
        }
    }
```

This is the full class (with the comments and non-relevant parts removed):

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class EntityBase<TSubclass> : INotifyPropertyChanged where TSubclass : class
{
    private List<string> _hydratedProperties = new List<string>();

    public bool IsPropertyHydrated(string propertyName)
    {
        return this._hydratedProperties.Contains(propertyName);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        string propertyName = GetPropertyName(expression);

        if (!this._hydratedProperties.Contains(propertyName)) { this._hydratedProperties.Add(propertyName); }

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Derived class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Bin : EntityBase<Bin>
{
    private Eta _eta;

    [DataMember]
    public Eta Eta
    {
        get { return this._eta; }

        set
        {
            this._eta = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => this.Eta);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is something setting it to `null` somewhere else? Set a breakpoint in the property and make the condition when `value == null` and see if it ever hits.

Comment: Could you provide a complete chunk of code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: No, nothing is setting it to null. I just created this new field and haven't set it to null anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @BobHorn Are you by chance writing to the list from multiple threads? If so you may need to implement locks or use threadsafe collections

Comment: can you provide sample class with this property and how you use it?

Comment: Check if propertyName = null. before the if statement. and also you may put a breakpoint before that and check if any of those variables are null

Comment: @JonathanCarroll, null not a _propertyName_, null a _hydratedProperties_

Comment: We really need the exact error message (including any variables mentioned) and a representative code sample that reproduces the bug.

Comment: I think he knows what a null exception is, and by now he knows what is coming null is _hidratedProperties. He needs to know why. From using notify property changed, might be in a data binding situation. Maybe a thread issue, hard to say.

Comment: @Grundy this is not a duplicate. This question is asking why is IT throwing a `NullReferenceException` not what IS a `NullReferenceException`...

Comment: @IronGeek, in duplicated question explain why it can happens and how it can be solved

Comment: I added the full class. Does that help? My concern is that the binding is causing a property change notification before the base class is fully initialized, if that's even possible. My other concern is that I could check for null and initialize it and add my value to it, but would that value get wiped out when it's eventually initialized?

Comment: can you add also sample derived class, and sample how you create it?

Comment: Sure. When I run the code, I hit the NotifyPropertyChanged() method many times before the actual field is initialized.

Comment: To me it looks like the problem is in the way you initialize the field. Try to initialize it in a constructor and see if it helps

Comment: I actually found another way to solve this issue. See my answer. If anyone has some feedback on it, that would be great. I'm especially curious to know if it should be considered *the* answer to this post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the clue:

```
[DataContract]
```

Yup. [`DataContractSerializer` does **not** call any constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1076735/3764814). Instead, it uses `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` to create the object that will be deserialized. This bypasses the constructor call.

Your initializer:

```
private List<string> _hydratedProperties = new List<string>();
```

is translated to an implicit default constructor by the compiler.

As a workaround, you can use [a deserialization callback with `OnDeserializingAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute.aspx):

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class EntityBase<TSubclass> : INotifyPropertyChanged
    where TSubclass : class
{
    private List<string> _hydratedProperties;

    protected EntityBase()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        _hydratedProperties = new List<string>()
    }

    [OnDeserializing]
    private void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        Init();
    }

    // ... rest of code here
}
```

Comment: Lucas: What about the answer I just posted? Should that be an acceptable way to solve this as well?

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler answer than what Lucas provided. I'm not sure if this one is actually better, but it's simple and it worked. All I did was add the `DataMember` attribute to the field. Since that specifies that the field is part of the data contract, it is included with serialization/deserialization and no longer causes a null reference error.

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class EntityBase<TSubclass> : INotifyPropertyChanged where TSubclass : class
{
    [DataMember]
    private List<string> _hydratedProperties = new List<string>();

    // More code here
}
```

Comment: That works too, but the property list obviously gets serialized too. I don't know your code to tell if that's good or bad for you, but it may have unintended consequences you should be aware of: if you need to do versioning and you deserialize a previous version of the class, you'll get the old list back - any properties you expect to be in that list and that you added later on won't be there anymore - which *may* break your code, depending on what you're doing with it afterwards. It'll also increase the payload size with redundant data. But if all of this is OK to you, then sure, go ahead.

Comment: Thanks, Lucas. The logic surrounding this code is only in memory and not persisted, so versioning isn't an issue. That's a good point about the payload though.