# private initialized variable not initializing

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate

I have a datacontract on an inherited, partial class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Domain
{
  [DataContract]
  public partial class IdCard : DomainObject<System.Int64>
  {
    private Group _grp;

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Group Grp
    {
        get { return _grp; }
        set { _grp = value; }
    }

    private bool _unproxized = true;
    public override object UnProxy()
    {
        if (this._unproxized)  // this prevents stackoverflow with cyclical references
        {
            this.Grp = (Group)this.Grp.UnProxy();
            this._unproxized = false;
        }

        return this;
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, the _unproxized is never set to true;  Any ideas why?

I know I can simply switch the logic around, but I'm curious why the member variable is not being initialized.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but how did you come to the conclusion that it isn't being initialized?

Comment: First,  I know that a boolean defaults to false.  Second, the code inside the conditional is never getting called.  Third, when I inspect it with a debugger during the conditional it is false.

Comment: "private initialized variable not initializing".  The title of the question is a paradox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has the instance that you are looking at been deserialized? During standard DataContract de-serialization no constructors are called and only DataMembers are assigned. The variable that you are looking at is not marked as a DataMember.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178645/how-does-wcf-deserialization-instantiate-objects-without-calling-a-constructor) describes the implementation of the behavior that you are seeing using an almost identical example.

Answer (score 2):

It's because when deserialising, the `DataContract serialiser` uses a type of reflection to create completely uninitialised object instances, to which it then applies data. That's why the `DataContract serialiser` doesn't require a parameterless constructor. (Even if you add one, it won't get called). If you mark the `_unproxied` field with a `[DataMember]` attribute, it will be true.

Comment: Nice explanation and it sounds rational, do you have any references to support that?  It sounds like a bug to me that should be reported to MS bug tracker (connect.microsoft.com)

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is you are using web/service references. In this case the code (private variable) never gets to the client.

Comment: You are correct, however, I'm talking about the server side variable.

Answer (score 0):

try to assign varibles in a constructor like this:

```
public IdCard()
{
    _unproxized = true;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, that is a solution.  I'm not asking for a solution though, I'm asking why it is not being initialized.