# Remove [Serializable] attribute before class

Tags: c#, serialization

When working with the *`XmlSerializer`*, it is important that you mark your types with the [*`Serializable`*] attribute, part of the *`SerializableAttribute`* class.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        string xml;
        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            Person p = new Person
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe",
                Age = 42
            };
            serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, p);
            xml = stringWriter.ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
        using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            Person p = (Person)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} is {2} years old", p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.Age);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the *`Person`* class is marked with *`Serializable`*. All members of the type are automatically serialized if they don't opt out.

However if I remove the *`Serializable`* attribute, the result is still same with it.

See the image.

[image]

Why? *`Serializable`* attribute is useless?

Comment: Yes it is useless. It is only used if, for example, you use BinaryFormatter or SoapFormatter,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When working with the XmlSerializer, it is important that you mark your types with the [Serializable] attribut

That is not correct.  Only some serializers rely on that attribute, but not XmlSerializer.

Note that there are a number of inconsistencies between the various serializers in the .NET framework.  Some will call a default constructor/execute field initializers, some will not.  Some will serialize private members, some will not.  Some use SerializableAttribute, some do not.

[How does WCF deserialization instantiate objects without calling a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178645/how-does-wcf-deserialization-instantiate-objects-without-calling-a-constructor/179486#179486)

Read up on the specifics of the serializer you are using to avoid surprises.